# Exoplayer seeking mp4 removes buffer

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I am working on a Video streaming application and I am using ExoPlayer as my video streamer.

How can I somehow cache or keep the buffer when I seek to a position before the currentPosition of the video.

Note that I am not using DASH or HLS and i am streaming in the traditional way.

```
DefaultHttpDataSource dataSource = new DefaultHttpDataSource("android", null);
ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
                uri,
                dataSource,
                allocator,
                buffer_segment_count * buffer_segment_size);
videoTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(context, sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT, 2000, new Handler(context.getMainLooper()), this, 1000);
audioTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, new Handler(context.getMainLooper()), this);
mPlayer.prepare(videoTrackRenderer, audioTrackRenderer);
```

I searched in the issues section and found out (if not wrong) that it keep the buffer for mp4 videos, but in my application it does not! The issues section is rather confusing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a datasource and it is working. In case you have the same problem you can find an answer [here](https://github.com/saeednt/ExoCacheDataSource).

If you are having a similar problem and your server structure seems to be different than mine, you can read the source for inspiration on how to fix the problem.